# How do the ASP.NET MVC engine use the View Shared Folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, shared-directory

We all know that we can define some partial view or common view under the shared folder.
So it can help us to reduce the duplicate views and they make the source code maintainable.

But What does the the MVC engine do to use the SharedView and How to merge the Control View and SharedView together?

I hope for you help.

Thank you.

Comment: MVC View Engine will search from View folder, then shared folder to find the view

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about what exactly you ask, but i assume you want to know what shared views are and how to use them in your project.

For the sake of example let's say you have homepage wich has a loginform. And lets assume if the person is logged in u want to show a hello (username) with some links specified to his account and if he is not logged in you want to show a login form. It's fine to hardcode this into the main controller view, but what if u want to show this form/loginstuff on every page of your application. This is a perfect scenario to use a partial.

In your partial you make the loginform or logged in welcome and links.

```
<div id="login">
@if(logged in)
{
   //show links
} else {
   //show form
}

</div>
```

Usually you put this partial in your main _Layout, but lets for the sake of example assume you want this partial to show up on 3 of your controller views, all you have to do within those views is:

```
@Html.Partial("_partialname")
```

You only need to put a partial in shared folder if multiple controller views are using it.